# Python Filenotfound error in a program to practice exam questions

Tags: python, file-not-found

I have little programming experience, but I'm trying to create a very simple program in Python from a set of many questions that look like this in .txt file:

*8001Penicilínové antibiotiká
0+   neúčinkujú na L-formy baktérií, mykoplazmy a riketsie
1-   zasahujú do syntézy cytoplazmatickej membrány baktérií
2+   účinkujú len na rastúce a deliace sa bunky
3-   ich základný účinok je bakteriostatický
4+   narúšajú zosieťovanie peptidoglykánu bunkovej steny
5-   môžu sa podať každému pacientovi
6+   sú netoxické, vhodné pre deti aj gravidné ženy
7-   u chlamýdií môže ich podanie indukovať tvorbu L-foriem
8+   môžu sa kombinovať s inhibítormi betalaktamáz
9-   účinkujú na pôvodcov atypickej pneumónie*

Where "8001" is the number of the question, the following text in the same line is the question itself, the numbers from 0 to 9 are possible answers, the ones with + are correct and should be marked as such in the program, the ones with - incorrect. I'm trying to create a program to choose a random question from the data, pick 4 random possible answers, and I'll have to write/press + or - with each answer and the program will correct me (for example with green or red colors for answers) and go to the next question.

I've tried to run the program using a file named "data.txt" with the questions and a Python code to read it, select the questions randomly, etc..
However, I've been getting the same error all the time while trying to run it in command prompt: file "data.txt" not found (**FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data.txt'**)
However, I have both saved in the same directory, on the desktop (I checked in properties), I gave permissions to read it.
I don't know what to do, I've tried to use many different ways to get it to work changing "def read_questions(filename):"

````
def load_questions(file_path):
    questions = []
    with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        question = {}
        for line in lines:
            if line.strip() == '':
                continue
            if line[0].isdigit():
                if question:
                    questions.append(question)
                question = {'text': line.strip(), 'answers': []}
            else:
                answer = {'text': line[1:].strip(), 'correct': line[0] == '+'}
                question['answers'].append(answer)
        if question:
            questions.append(question)
    return questions

def display_question(question):
    print(question['text'])
    for i, answer in enumerate(question['answers']):
        print(f"{i}. {answer['text']}")

def get_user_answers(question):
    user_answers = []
    for i, answer in enumerate(question['answers']):
        while True:
            user_input = input(f"Is answer {i} correct or incorrect? (+/-): ")
            if user_input == '+' or user_input == '-':
                user_answers.append(user_input == '+')
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid input. Please enter + or -.")
    return user_answers

def display_results(question, user_answers):
    for i, answer in enumerate(question['answers']):
        if answer['correct'] == user_answers[i]:
            print(f"{answer['text']} - Correct")
        else:
            print(f"{answer['text']} - Incorrect")

def main():
    file_path = r'C:\Users\thejy\OneDrive\Desktop\data.txt'
    questions = load_questions(file_path)
    while True:
        question = random.choice(questions)
        random.shuffle(question['answers'])
        display_question(question)
        user_answers = get_user_answers(question)
        display_results(question, user_answers)
        input("Press enter to continue...")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()```

I'll be very glad for any help or guidance!
````

Comment: You didn't post the code of the program. It's hard to debug something you cannot see :/

Comment: Show your code please if you don't mind

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hey, sorry, I just added the code. Thanks a lot for help!